# Popover en Modal of Bootstrap 3.0.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popover

I have a form in a Modal and when I do click in "Send" this must show a popover with the word "Thanks you", but When I click the first time, the popover is not displayed, but from the second time onwards and shows good.

My code is here

```js
$(document).on('submit', 'form#contact',function(event) {
    $('#submit').popover({ trigger:'click', content: 'Gracias por tu opinion', placement: 'left' });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

jsfiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/gonzalesc/T348e/**

Something I'm doing wrong, because the popover should show from the first time that I do click
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happends is, that in your first click, or submit, you insert the popover to the submit button :

```js
$('#submit').popover({ trigger:'click', content: 'Gracias por tu opinion', placement: 'left' });
```

with `trigger : 'click'`. This means, that the popover only will be shown *next* time the user clicks on the submit button. To show the popover immediately, do this :

```js
$('#submit').popover({ trigger: "manual", content: 'Gracias por tu opinion', placement: 'left' }).popover('show');
```

change trigger to `manual`, and force the popover to be shown by `.popover('show')`.

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LWeYF/**